# Remove duplicate HTML element innerText with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to remove a duplicated HTML element's `innerText`. I have tried many solutions but don't get a good result. I don't want to use jQuery; only pure JS.

If it can be solved by CSS, it's better for me. I've tried many things.

My Tryings:

1) First i have try to remove duplicated array values before append html but its very complicated and its not suitable for my experience.

2) I have got an ideo of hiding the same innerText of element.

3) I have try to use this method bu get faild.

```
Array.from(elements).forEach( (el) => {
     el.innerText = "foo";
});
```

My items:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yilOb.png)

My code:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF5vi.png)

```
<div id="LastDocuments">
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 13.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 10.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 10.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 10.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 10.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 10.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 13.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 13.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 18.exam</div>
</div>
```

Below ansvers I have found solution. Thanks

Comment: please don't use code as images...

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Comment: Post the code in question not as image type.

Comment: im so sory, im new to use. I have changed.

Comment: Lars Peterson Answer solved by problem.

Comment: @Sinful Please mark my answer as the accepted answer. This way I get rewarded for answering.

Comment: How can I do ? @Lars Peterson

Comment: @Sinful Right by my answer is a little check mark. Just click that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will store used names in an array, and if another item with the same name comes up, it will remove it.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.ldTitle');
var arrayOfUsedNames = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
  var index = arrayOfUsedNames.indexOf(elements[i].innerHTML);

  if (index == -1)
  {
    arrayOfUsedNames.push(elements[i].innerHTML);
  } 

  else
  {
    elements[i].parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elements[i].parentNode);
  }

}

console.log(arrayOfUsedNames);
```

Just tested it with your HTML, works perfect :)

Comment: Using an array for tracking the texts is not the most efficient though.

Comment: @trincot Like he will be handling 10k indexes of text :-/ . With small amounts of data, there's no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to keep track of those texts you already found:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
    const st = new Set();
    for (const div of document.querySelectorAll('.LastDocument')) {
        if (st.has(div.textContent.trim())) {
            div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        }
        st.add(div.textContent.trim());
    }
}
```

```js
function removeDuplicates() {
    const st = new Set();
    for (const div of document.querySelectorAll('.LastDocument')) {
        if (st.has(div.textContent.trim())) {
            div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        }
        st.add(div.textContent.trim());
    }
}

removeDuplicates();
```

```html
<div id="LastDocuments">
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 13.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 10.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 10.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 10.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 10.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 10.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 13.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 13.exam</div>
</div>
<div class="LastDocument">
    <div class="ldImgDiv"><img class="ldImg" src="./images/ic_sinav.svg"></div>
    <div class="ldTitle">Sınav 18.exam</div>
</div>
```

The variable `st` is a `Set`, i.e. it holds a collection of values, but guarantees that they are unique. A `Set` can answer in constant time whether a value is already in the Set or not (using [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)), which makes it superior for this purpose than using an `Array` (`indexOf` does not run in constant, but in linear time).

Then [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is used to get the list of elements we're interested in. The argument `.LastDocument` is a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), and thus the list of elements will be those elements that have class `LastDocument`.

This list is iterated over with a [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

For each element the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is taken (and [trimmed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), but this may not be really necessary). If that text value already exists in the set, the element is removed from its [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) with [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).

Then the text value is [added](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add) to the Set. Note that this does not have any effect if the Set already has the text.

Comment: I dont understand your code but its working too. Thank you so much.

Comment: Explanation added. Let me know if something is unclear.